# How do you input 2 files then output them in python?

Tags: python, html, input

I have a code written for a webpage and I need to know how to take 2 data files and import them into an array then output the data in a table on my html site.

the 2 data files are txt files that are on my computer

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far and what doesn't work.

Comment: Where are these two data files? Are they provided by the user or do they reside in your server somewhere?

Comment: What is the data format?

Comment: We ain't mind-readers! What is in file A? What is in file B? Which bits of A and B go where in the final table? You want this to run every time someone requests this page, or only when one of the files changes? How often do the files change? Are you using a web framework, and if so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm going to take a guess that you want to just create an html table that has 1 line per data line in the text file.

```
file1=open("input1.txt",'rU')
file2=open("input2.txt",'rU')
lines = file1.readlines() + file2.readlines()
html = "<html>\n<body>\n<table>"
for line in lines:
  html += "<tr><td>" + line + "</td></tr>\n"
html += "</table>\n</body>\n</html>"

output = open('output_file.html','w')
output.write(html)
```

I don't know if that is what you were looking for, but that does what I said above.

Comment: That is what i need however it does not open

Comment: What do you mean by not opening? Does the input not open? Does the output not open? Does the program itself not open?